# How To Put Data In 2D Array from Dataset Using Loop C#?

Tags: c#

i am trying to put data in a 2d array but getting error it add value to 0,0 position then 1,0 position and so on please make it correct

```
int count = output.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
string[,] terms = new string[count,2]; 
for (int runs = 0; runs < count; runs++)
{
    terms[0,runs] =output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][0].ToString();
    terms[0,runs] =output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][2].ToString();
}
```

Hopes for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
terms[runs,0] =output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][0].ToString();
terms[runs,1] =output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][2].ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this should work...

```
int count = output.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
string[,] terms = new string[count,2]; 
for (int runs = 0; runs < count; runs++)
{
   terms[runs,0] =output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][0].ToString();
   terms[runs,1] =output.Tables[0].Rows[runs][2].ToString();
}
```

you have defined a 2d array of n rows and 2 columns, but in your for you are looping trought the columns

```
terms[0,runs]
```

so you get an index error....